# Loop asynchronous call and join the returned promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I'm working on my first nodejs application which is using bluebird. I've a requirement to call an asynchronous method inside a for loop which returns a promise for each call. I want to combine all those promises together, how can I achieve this. Any help is much appreciated.

I'm retrieving set of documents from mongodb and I need to loop through that returned set of documents and pass a field as a parameter to an asynchronous method which returns a promise. Since i'm doing this in the loop I need a way to combine all of those promises in to one single promise.

Comment: You will ALWAYS get a better and more specific answer taylored to your particular situation if you include your relevant code.  Probably because you are using Bluebird, you can use some of their nifty functions (like `Promise.map()` to simplify your code, but we can't tell for sure until you include your actual code.  Questions about code should always include some of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.all()` method : http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html

Example :

```
var promises = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    promises.push(yourPromise);
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) {
    // All your promises are resolved
    // Promises results are stored in values argument
    console.log(values);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Promise.all([promise 1,promise 2,promise 3]).then(data=>{
     console.log(data);
});
After executing all these 
data[0] contains promise 1 result, 
data[1] contains promise 2 result,
data[2] contains promise 3 result
```

Note: Promise.all()  will fail if at least one of its promises failed or rejected.